# How to get the current logged in user in laravel middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to get the currently logged in user from my custom middleware like this:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->getKey();
```

but i get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

any idea?

Comment: It might return `null` when you're not logged in

Comment: Yes, it's returning null, but i'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling the Column Name of your users table;

```
Auth::user()->ColumnNameInYourUsersTable;
```

You can also do `auth()->user()->ColumnNameInYourUsersTable;`

Make sure you include `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at top.

-- EDIT --

If you use different guard do it like this

`auth()->guard('guardname')->user()->ColumnNameInYourUsersTable;`

Comment: It'll only return null if you use different guard or you're not logged in at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to test if the user is logged in first.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->getKey();
}
```

Or if you just want the user id, you can simply do

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
```

No check is needed here because Laravel will do it for you

Answer (score -1):

For getting user do this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Make sure you import use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at top.

and for getting column value use this :

```
Auth::user()->yourColumnName;
```

**Alternative :**
If it is returning **NULL** then this solution will work.
Actually routes that uses sessions should be in **web** middleware group. This is a change in Laravel 5.2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // routes
});
```

and you can also move your **web** middleware groups to global middlewares in here  `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
];
```

Comment: Tried it but it's not reach the middleware?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-return-null-on-laravel-52 Try this buddy

Comment: It's return the login page ,but the route in my middleware should run in the background and not asking the user to login?

Comment: Did you moved your routes to web middleware group ? @MohammadAL-Raoosh

Comment: No , i make a middleware group and add the web middleware to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115631/discussion-between-iftikhar-uddin-and-mohammad-al-raoosh).